# Replace the field value in word document using Openxml

Tags: c#, xml, openxml

I am developing an application in which I am accessing the word document xml from Microsoft Dynamics CRM and want to replace the fields which were added through XML Mapping pane.

Below is the XML which is retrieved through the OpenXML.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<w:document xmlns:wpc="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingCanvas" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:r="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships" xmlns:m="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/math" xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:wp14="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingDrawing" xmlns:wp="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/wordprocessingDrawing" xmlns:w10="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main" xmlns:w14="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordml" xmlns:w15="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2012/wordml" xmlns:wpg="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingGroup" xmlns:wpi="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingInk" xmlns:wne="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2006/wordml" xmlns:wps="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingShape" mc:Ignorable="w14 w15 wp14"><w:body><w:sdt><w:sdtPr><w:id w:val="1519887787"/><w:placeholder><w:docPart w:val="DefaultPlaceholder_1081868574"/></w:placeholder><w:dataBinding w:prefixMappings="xmlns:ns0='urn:microsoft-crm/document-template/new_candidate/10006/' " w:xpath="/ns0:DocumentTemplate[1]/new_candidate[1]/new_candidatename[1]" w:storeItemID="{2D909ED6-F428-47C5-93D4-89B5709D4B5C}"/><w:text/></w:sdtPr><w:sdtContent><w:p w:rsidR="0055490F" w:rsidRDefault="00F5486B"><w:r><w:t>new_candidatename</w:t></w:r></w:p></w:sdtContent></w:sdt><w:bookmarkStart w:id="0" w:name="_GoBack" w:displacedByCustomXml="prev"/><w:bookmarkEnd w:id="0" w:displacedByCustomXml="prev"/><w:sectPr w:rsidR="0055490F"><w:pgSz w:w="11906" w:h="16838"/><w:pgMar w:top="1701" w:right="1134" w:bottom="1701" w:left="1134" w:header="708" w:footer="708" w:gutter="0"/><w:cols w:space="708"/><w:docGrid w:linePitch="360"/></w:sectPr></w:body></w:document>
```

In the above XML, there is one field called new_candidatename, which I want to replace with my custom value.

Can anyone please suggest me how do I replace the value using OpenXML?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using c# there is no reason to use openxml.  You can use xml linq library.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);
            XElement t = doc.Descendants().Where(x => x.Name.LocalName == "t").FirstOrDefault();
            t.Value = "New Value";

            doc.Save(FILENAME);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Let me try this and will let you know the result.